# Пишу бота в библиотеке pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

Создаю юзер бота в библиотеке pyrogram. как сделать так, чтобы упоминался рандомный пользователь группы после после предложения "скачиваю фотографии пользователя"?

````
def photo(_, msg):
    perc = 0
 
    while(perc < 100):
        try:
            text = " скачиваю фотографии пользователя " + str(perc) + "%"
            msg.edit(text)
 
            perc += random.randint(1, 3)
            sleep(0.1)
 
        except FloodWait as e:
            sleep(e.x)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать "базу" id, которые ты получишь и занести в список. Потом с помощью рандома сделать то что тебе нужно.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое за ответ!